# Composer hangs on installing framework

Tags: windows-7, xampp, composer-php

I've tried to install yii2

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0 -vvv
```

but everytime I run this command composer just hangs on different places and I can't install it. The same problem is with laravel. It hangs for few hours without doing anything.
The same thing happens with laravel

Is there solution for it?

Comment: Do you get any output? What operating system are you using?

Comment: No output it just hangs there. I'm using Win7 and Xampp

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from `composer diagnose` ?

Comment: i have exactly same because of xdebug on